# Web Page returns status 500

Tags: php, server

I've a PHP website. I edited a page and uploaded via filezilla. I tested in a local wamp server and the page works fine with no PHP errors. But when I replace the new file and refresh the page, the server returns a status 500 internal server error. There are no page errors but still the error consists. What am I doing wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: Check in firebug . Are you calling right path may be u forgot to remove some local setting variable.

Comment: i think you uploaded a `.htaccess` file which was configured for wamp and its not compatible with your web server settings. Status code 500 is **500 Internal Server Error**

Comment: You either need to post code or error log for us to help.

Comment: @zerkms And server log.